# SQL Stored Procedure - Error running when code length > 8,000

Tags: sql, stored-procedures

I have a SQL Store Procedure that gives output from multiple DBs. It looks like this (when the body of the code is Less than 8000 characters, it is running fine. But when I am adding more to the code it is giving random error "Incorrect Syntax"). Please help me resolve.

```
GO
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
Create proc [dbo].[ALR_PolTest_pn] 
@svr varchar(255),   --- Server
@NEWRDM varchar(255), ---- DB Name
@OLDRDM varchar(255), ---- DB Name
@NEWEDM varchar(255),  ---- DB Name
@OLDEDM varchar(255), ---- DB Name
@NEWPort varchar(255), ---- DB ID
@OLDPort varchar(255), ---- DB ID
@output nvarchar (max)
AS
DECLARE @SQL1       AS nVarchar(Max)
SET @SQL1 = '

--- THE CODE BODY

'
Exec(@SQL1)



exec dbo.[ALR_PolTest_pn] 
'pwbpdscatfrms01',--svr
'R_1Q2020_04132020_ER_USC_V2',-- NEW RDM
'R_2019Q4_DC2_01222020_EER_USC_NC',-- OLD RDM
'E_1Q2020_04132020_ER_USC_V2',-- NEW EDM
'E_2019Q4_DC2_01222020_EER_USC_NC',-- OLD EDM
'3',-- NEW PORT IDs
'3',-- OLD PORT IDs
'' --- OUTPUT
```

Comment: Which dbms are you using? (That code is product specific.)

Comment: 8000 characters is likely the upper limit. Why do you need to execute such a large dynamic query? Can't you split it up into multiple procedures?

Comment: The dynamic query is running fine directly on SQL. However not when converted to Stored Procedure and executing it. The format of the report requires it to run combined.